# Can I use an ellipsis (three dots) when I'm about to tell a story?

Tags: punctuation, ellipses, periods, sentence-ends

Consider the following sentence:

> So how this method is useful, you might say. Here's the story.

and then I'm telling the story from a new paragraph. So my question is can I use an ellipsis at the end of the last sentence, like this:

> So how this method is useful, you might say. Here's the story...

or is just a dot enough?

Comment: Using an ellipsis like this is not unknown in creative writing (fiction) or in casual email/messaging, but it might be frowned upon in more formal writing as it's not really a proper function of ellipses.

Comment: This is certainly done.  There are several different ways to handle this sort of transition.

Comment: "So how is this method useful?" you might ask. Let me explain with a story..."

Comment: Your first sentence is a syntactical train wreck. So see my comment above for a possible correction.